# How i can see loaded web page when web view has loaded web page?

Tags: android, android-webview

Trying this code....

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WebView browser = new WebView(this);
    browser.setWebViewClient( new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.d("URL LOADED!!!", url);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        };
    });




    setContentView(browser);
    browser.loadUrl("http://www.kinopoisk.ru");
    Log.d("web page loaded", "true");
}
```

but I haven't seen debug info about loaded page... no tag "URL LOADED!!!" in log cat

Comment: do you see the log from this statement `Log.d("web page loaded", "true");` ?

Comment: yes, but no "URL LOADED!!!" in log cat

Comment: `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` only gets called when the user clicks a link within the web page, not upon the initial load (now at least, I think I vaguely recall reading something about its behavior changing at some point in Androids history, so maybe it used to work the way you are expecting.)

Comment: So, how can I see loaded url, if it initial by loadUrl, not by click?

Answer (score 0):

If you are the one calling loadUrl() it should be on whatever url you've passed to it. So I don't understand what your use case would be for needing to know the url right after you've manually given it a url. But regardless you should be able to use [WebView.getUrl()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getUrl%28%29) like this to find it:

```
browser.getUrl();
```